# how does searchsort in python work?

Tags: python, search, scipy, sortedlist

To make my question clear
say if I have an array a as
Out[123]: [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 54]
When I try to search the numbers in the list, searchsort returns correct value but when I try something not in the list, it returns an absurd value

here is some of the results

```
In [131]: a
Out[131]: [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 54]

In [132]: searchsorted(a,1)
Out[132]: 0

In [133]: searchsorted(a,6)
Out[133]: 3

In [134]: searchsorted(a,[9,54,1])
Out[134]: array([4, 6, 0])

In [135]: searchsorted(a,[9,54,1,0])
Out[135]: array([4, 6, 0, 0])
***> # here 0 is not in the list, but turns up @ position 0***

In [136]: searchsorted(a,740)
Out[136]: 7
***> # here 0 is not in the list, but turns up @ position 7***
```

why is this happening?

Comment: What is `searchsorted`?

Comment: `searchsorted` is clearly not a builtin.

Comment: @Volatility `searchsorted` is a numpy/scipy function.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`searchsorted` tells you *where* the element belongs to guarantee ordering:

> Find the indices into a sorted array a **such that, if the corresponding elements in v were inserted before the indices, the order of a would be preserved.**

inserting `740` at position 7 would preserve ordering, as would inserting 0 at position 0.

Comment: If you want to determine whether a number is in an array, you can use `==` and `nonzero` to do this: `len((a == 740)[0])` is zero.

Comment: Thanx @jozzas got it. I thought it perform binary search.

Comment: Or you could do `740==a[searchsorted(a, 740)]`, to still make use of the binary search.

Answer (score 3):

`searchsorted` doesn't tell you where things *are,* it tells you where things *should go* to keep the list sorted.

So `0` would have to be inserted at position 0, before the `1`. Similarly, `740` needs to be inserted at position 7, beyond the current end of the list.

You can see this by reading the docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

> **numpy.searchsorted(a, v, side='left', sorter=None)**
>
> Find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.
>
> Find the indices into a sorted array a such that, if the corresponding elements in v were inserted before the indices, the order of a would be preserved.

Comment: It also can tell you where things that *are* in the index are, if the value you are looking for is located at the `'left'` index. Using binary search to determine containment is still the fastest method to do so.

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) it states that it uses [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to spot insertion point of an item in a sorted list.

the word 'insertion point' means, if item I is inserted to the insertion point index N in sorted array A, the array A will remain sorted with new item I.

your examples like `[9, 54, 1]` is meaningless since the array is not sorted.

you can use `bisect` module in python to do the same thing, without numpy.

Comment: `[9,54,1]` isn't the list to search, it's a list of items to return the insertion points in `a` _for._ It works fine, see the output of it.

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah, I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

**searchsorted(initial_list,insert_list,side)
default: side = 'left'**

```
For example: searchsorted(x,v)
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
v = [-10,10,2,3]
```

[This is my result of my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJtpb.jpg)

:)

Comment: Please format the code sample and include the result as text in your answer. If imgur stops hosting the image in the future, readers will lose access to a significant part of your answer.